# How much business logic to utilize at breeze level?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api2, breeze

I've recently started working with Breeze.js and ASP.NET Web API2. I followed through several tutorials, videos, etc... but couldn't really find a proper answer to the following question.

How much business logic processing should you perform at breeze level and how much you should do at the API level. For example, when using breeze, is all what the API does is return getall() or getbyID() type of data filtering? Let's say we want to get a set of records by joining two tables. Normally what we do is get all these data in the server side and create one viewmodel and push it back to the client. But with breeze, since we can manage the data at the client side, should we do that?

Take an example like where you have Employee & Department table, with FkDepartmentID in Employee table, but in the client side you need Department Name. My question is whether to do this retrieval using breeze or through the web api itslef.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the "business logic processing" refers to data retrieval options, I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all answer.  Here's a few use cases and approaches using strictly breeze to retrieve the data in the "shape" that's needed for the UI work:

### I want to display an employee entity, including the name of their department.

Consider loading the employee using a [single relation expand](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples#SingleExpand).  This will ensure the department is loaded along with the employee, enabling access to the department name via the employee.Department.Name property.

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Employees')
    .where('EmployeeId', '==', 22)
    .expand('Department');
```

### I want to use a form to edit an employee entity, using a `<select>` element to choose their department.

Consider loading the employee without expanding it's department.  Separately, load the [lookup list](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/lookup-lists) of department entities so that you can create the select element's options.

### I want to display a read-only list of employees.

Consider using a [projection query](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples#Projection) to get an array of objects with the properties you need to display.

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Employees')
    .where('LastName', FilterQueryOp.StartsWith, 'C')
    .select('FirstName, LastName, Department.Name')
    .orderBy('LastName');
```

Comment: Good answer, Jeremy. The term "business logic" is always nebulous. Are we talking about data accessibility? validation rules? processes? security? communications?  Some kinds of logic belong on the client, some only on the server, some on both. It's not something we can make a blanket statement about. We can say confidently that you can put your logic wherever is appropriate. Breeze doesn't dictate choices, but it does create options that you might not have without it.